# Intellij + Bazel Error when compiling Java headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, bazel

I am learning Spring Boot and am working through [this example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/tree/master/examples/spring_boot) using Intellij.

#### Problem:

- Intellij's Bazel button -->  errors (see example below)

  - This is the small green icon top right "Sync Project with BUILD Files"
  - `@CrossOrigin` annotation causes the error during sandbox compilation or something.
- Running command manually `bazel build //src/main/java/hello:app` --> builds just fine

#### My understanding of the problem so far:

- Intellij's `bazel build` command includes a flag, `--output_groups=intellij-resolve-java-direct-deps`, that checks implicit dependencies (see full command + error below).
- Normal `bazel build //src/main/java/hello:app` obviously doesn't include this flag and builds + runs fine.

#### Questions:

- Does anyone know what exactly this flag does?
- The error is confusing, stating that it's looking for "another annotation parameter" but I don't believe this to be accurate. If not, what exactly is the parameter I'm supposed to supply? ...and what is `<clinit>`?

##### Error Command + Output

```
/usr/bin/bazel build --tool_tag=ijwb:IDEA:community --keep_going --build_event_binary_file=/tmp/intellij-bep-ef1a54af-ac18-480c-b813-050e261d0a4f --nobuild_event_binary_file_path_conversion --curses=no --color=yes --progress_in_terminal_title=no --noexperimental_run_validations --aspects=@intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect --override_repository=intellij_aspect=/home/jordan/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/ijwb/aspect --output_groups=intellij-resolve-java-direct-deps -- //src/main/java/hello:app
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //src/main/java/hello:app (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
INFO: Analyzed target //src/main/java/hello:app (5 packages loaded, 184 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 39] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt

ERROR: /home/jordan/Documents/swe/rules_jvm_external/examples/spring_boot/src/main/java/hello/BUILD:1:13: Compiling Java headers src/main/java/hello/liblib-hjar.jar (2 source files) failed: (Exit 1): java failed: error executing command external/remotejdk11_linux/bin/java -Xverify:none -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:-CompactStrings '--patch-module=java.compiler=external/remote_java_tools_linux/java_tools/java_compiler.jar' ... (remaining 42 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
src/main/java/hello/HelloController.java:7: error: missing required annotation argument: <clinit>
@CrossOrigin
^
src/main/java/hello/HelloController.java:11: error: missing required annotation argument: <clinit>
    @CrossOrigin
    ^
Aspect @intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect of //src/main/java/hello:app failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.460s, Critical Path: 0.33s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
INFO: Build Event Protocol files produced successfully.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

#### Successful Command + Output

(removed flag `--output_groups=intellij-resolve-java-direct-deps`)

```
/usr/bin/bazel build --tool_tag=ijwb:IDEA:community --keep_going --build_event_binary_file=/tmp/intellij-bep-ef1a54af-ac18-480c-b813-050e261d0a4f --nobuild_event_binary_file_path_conversion --curses=no --color=yes --progress_in_terminal_title=no --noexperimental_run_validations --aspects=@intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect --override_repository=intellij_aspect=/home/jordan/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/ijwb/aspect -- //src/main/java/hello:app
Loading: 
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //src/main/java/hello:app (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
INFO: Analyzed target //src/main/java/hello:app (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 1] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
Aspect @intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect of //src/main/java/hello:app up-to-date (nothing to build)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.034s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build Event Protocol files produced successfully.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

Answer (score 0):

Bazel is still working to support Java 11 and there are Java annotation processors which appear to be hardcoded to JDK 8.

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8585) which refers to a

- [Temporary fix](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8585#issuecomment-583859533)

  - `--java_header_compilation=false`
  - Note that this won't solve the issue when using Intellij's bazel button. This will only fix running the command manually (with the `--java_header_compilation=false` flag).
- [Long-term fix](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/10ffddb13ac070f2c6b9d64cb927ab3b659c0b72) in the upcoming release (6.0.0)

  - I installed the pre-release 6.0.0 Bazel from the source code using [these directions](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/install-compile-source.html), which includes the implemented fix. **This solved the problem**. Now I can use two different releases of bazel - 6.0.0 by calling `bazel_dev` or the latest main release (4.2.1) by simply calling `bazel`.
  - Point to `/some/path/to/bazel_dev` binary in Intellij's Bazel settings.